# Target a css class in 'a component generated by library' in react

Tags: css, reactjs, react-component

I have used a chart library. I want to target and modify the properties of the CSS class generated by that library using external CSS. Let's assume the code in inspector is like this-

```
<div id="apexcharts9xagqubx" class="apexcharts-canvas apexcharts9xagqubx apexcharts-theme-light" style="width: 319.5px; height: 200px;">
  <svg id="SvgjsSvg1001" width="319.5" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" class="apexcharts-svg apexcharts-zoomable hovering-zoom">
<div>
```

the apex chart documentation says I can target `.apexcharts-canvas` and change the background color. I have done this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactApexChart from 'react-apexcharts'
import './apex.module.css'
return (
  <div id="chart">
    <ReactApexChart options={data.options} series={data.series} type="area" height={200}/>
  </div>
);
```

inside `apex.module.css` I did this:

```
.apexcharts-canvas{
  background-color: black;
}
```

now what?
looks like it doesn't work.

Comment: You might be able to get around it by creating a custom CSS class in your own CSS file, using the `!important` flag where necessary, and applying it with the `className` prop of the component.

Comment: @mattbbc how can I implement a custom css class in a highly nested div inside of that component?

Comment: Are you using CSS Modules or some similar system that munges classnames so they don't conflict between components?  If so your `.apexcharts-canvas` is getting compiled into something like `.apexcharts-canvas-gE35CF` and you need more in the CSS file to tell it not to do that.

Comment: You could try adding the `!important` flag to the `background-color` value you've implemented.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a CSS specifity thing.

You could try including the parent in the selector:

```css
#chart .apexcharts-canvas {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Hey friend*** when you import a css file with module prefix you shouldn't import that way, that kind of file will be imported giving it a name for example in this image: [image]

[image]

This works equally with css extension files, since I am doing it with scss, this rule is for all css file types.
When you declare with module it's not a global style anymore but a style for a component because there is another way to import it but without the prefix module, in the image I already showed you the name of the declared name and then the name of the class.
Luckily my friend, it is not so complicated, I am also learning this little by little.

Comment: I know this. I use this when I impose my own css class. But in this case. I want to target a css class what is already inside of that component library. now how can I select that? That is my question.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using CSS modules (else let me know):

---

**TL;DR**

You can either target the HTML *element* (instead of its class) where `.apexcharts-canvas` class is used (**option 1**), or you can make sure the global CSS imports are compatible with the CSS modules (**option 2**), checking webpack configuration.

---

I had same issue, I wanted to edit a CSS class in Apexcharts.
I am assumming you are using CSS modules (.module.css).

**Option 1**

Use this option if:

- you used [cra](https://create-react-app.dev/) or you do not want to edit webpack configuration
- it is enough to target the HTML *element* instead of the class directly

Steps:

1. The ID of the div where the chart is should be namespaced (CSS modules): `id={styles.chart}`, with CSS modules file imported as `import styles from 'path-to-file'`
2. In code inspector find div with `chart` id
3. Drill down until you find HTML element with your class `.apexcharts-canvas`
4. In your CSS modules file, target the HTML element with `.apexcharts-canvas`, using CSS selectors (example below)

   .chart > div > div > :last-child {
   background-color: black;
   }

**Option 2**

Use this option if:

- you can access the webpack config file (not using [cra](https://create-react-app.dev/)), AND
- you want to target class directly

In the webpack configuration, you need to create a rule not only for CSS modules (`import styles from 'path-to-file'`), but also for global (normal) CSS (`import 'path-to-other-file'`).

(credit: [link](https://dev.to/codeprototype/configuring-both-css-modules-and-global-css-for-reactjs-in-webpack-4ci7))

```
    rules: [
  {
    test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          importLoaders: 1,
          modules: {
            localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
          },
        }
      }
    ],
    include: /\.module\.css$/
  },
  {
    test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      'css-loader'
    ],
    exclude: /\.module\.css$/
  },
]
```

After that you can import a global CSS file (`import 'path-to-other-file'`) with a class `.apexcharts-canvas` on it.

**Important**: the webpack rules are mutually exclusive. Files ending with ".module.css" are considered CSS modules, other CSS files not ending like that are global CSS imports.